# Keras loss is NaN when training for semantic segmentation

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

I am using the headsegmentation dataset. A single mask looks like this

[image]

All mask images are a single channel. This is my code:

```
image_size = 512
batch = 4
labels = 14
data_directory = "/content/headsegmentation_final/"
sample_train_images = len(os.listdir(data_directory + 'Training/Images/')) - 1
sample_validation_images = len(os.listdir(data_directory + 'Validation/Images/')) - 1
test_images = len(os.listdir('/content/headsegmentation_final/Test/')) - 1

t_images = sorted(glob(os.path.join(data_directory, "Training/Images/*")))[:sample_train_images]
t_masks = sorted(glob(os.path.join(data_directory, "Training/Category_ids/*")))[:sample_train_images]
v_images = sorted(glob(os.path.join(data_directory, "Validation/Images/*")))[:sample_validation_images]
v_masks = sorted(glob(os.path.join(data_directory, "Validation/Category_ids/*")))[:sample_validation_images]
ts_images = sorted(glob(os.path.join(data_directory, "Test/*")))[:test_images]

def image_augmentation(img, random_range):
    img = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(img)
    img = tfa.image.rotate(img, random_range)

    return img

def image_process(path, mask=False):
    img = tf.io.read_file(path)

    upper = 90 * (math.pi/180.0) # degrees -> radian
    lower = 0 * (math.pi/180.0)
    ran_range = random.uniform(lower, upper)

    if mask == True:
        img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=1)
        img.set_shape([None, None, 1])
        img = tf.image.resize(images=img, size=[image_size, image_size])
        #img = image_augmentation(img, ran_range)

    else:
        img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
        img.set_shape([None, None, 3])
        img = tf.image.resize(images=img, size=[image_size, image_size])
        img = img / 127.5 - 1
        #img = image_augmentation(img, ran_range)

    return img

def data_loader(image_list, mask_list):
    img = image_process(image_list)
    mask = image_process(mask_list, mask=True)
    return img, mask

def data_generator(image_list, mask_list):

    cihp_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_list, mask_list))
    cihp_dataset = cihp_dataset.map(data_loader, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    cihp_dataset = cihp_dataset.batch(batch, drop_remainder=True)

    return cihp_dataset

train_dataset = data_generator(t_images, t_masks)
val_dataset = data_generator(v_images, v_masks)

def block(block_input, filters = 256, kernel = 3, dilation = 1, padding = "same", use_bias = False,):
    x = layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size = kernel, dilation_rate = dilation, padding = "same", use_bias = use_bias, kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.HeNormal(),)(block_input)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def DSP_pooling(dsp_pooling_input):
    dims = dsp_pooling_input.shape
    x = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(dims[-3], dims[-2]))(dsp_pooling_input)
    x = block(x, kernel = 1, use_bias = True)
    pool_output = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(dims[-3] // x.shape[1], dims[-2] // x.shape[2]), interpolation="bilinear",)(x)

    block_output_1 = block(dsp_pooling_input, kernel=1, dilation=1)
    block_out_6 = block(dsp_pooling_input, kernel=3, dilation=6)
    block_out_12 = block(dsp_pooling_input, kernel=3, dilation=12)
    block_out_18 = block(dsp_pooling_input, kernel=3, dilation=18)

    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([pool_output, block_output_1, block_out_6, block_out_12, block_out_18])

    output = block(x, kernel=1)
    
    return output

def DeepLabV3_ResNet50(size, classes):
    input = keras.Input(shape=(size, size, 3))

    resnet50 = keras.applications.ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor = input)
    x = resnet50.get_layer("conv4_block6_2_relu").output
    x = DSP_pooling(x)

    a = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(size // 4 // x.shape[1], size // 4 // x.shape[2]),interpolation="bilinear",)(x)
    b = resnet50.get_layer("conv2_block3_2_relu").output
    b = block(b, filters = 48, kernel = 1)

    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([a, b])
    x = block(x)
    x = block(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(size=(size // x.shape[1], size // x.shape[2]),interpolation="bilinear",)(x)

    output = layers.Conv2D(classes, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same")(x)

    return keras.Model(inputs = input, outputs = output)

model = DeepLabV3_ResNet50(size = image_size, classes = labels)

def scheduler(epoch, lr):
  if epoch < 10:
    return lr
  else:
    return lr * tf.math.exp(-0.1)

loss = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=loss, metrics=["accuracy"])
round(model.optimizer.lr.numpy(), 5)

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(scheduler)

history = model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data = val_dataset, epochs = 25, callbacks = [callback], verbose=1)
round(model.optimizer.lr.numpy(), 5)
```

This is the output:

```
Epoch 1/25
1404/1404 [==============================] - 342s 232ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5888 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4956 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 2/25
1404/1404 [==============================] - 323s 230ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5892 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4956 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 3/25
1404/1404 [==============================] - 323s 230ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.5892 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4956 - lr: 0.0010
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you understand how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with DeepLabV3+. First of all, you may want to check this site https://keras.io/examples/vision/deeplabv3_plus/ as they have a similar code as yours and use the same CIHP dataset.

To solve my issue, I went over several solutions I found on the internet, such as smaller learning rate, weight initialization, different loss function, gradient clipping, etc. If the above link doesn't help you, you can try each of them but I doubt they will work for you because they didn't work for me and your above code seems pretty fine.

The problem probably results from the issue that the actual labels in the masks are outside the classes or labels you assigned. For example, you, here, assigned 14 as the number of classes/labels but in the masks, there should be more than 14 labels in fact, so you are getting NaN loss. This was the case with me. You should adjust the number of labels/classes used in the model to the one existing in the mask dataset. Here is how you can do it:

```
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
    
# Check labels for all masks
def check_mask_labels(masks):
    
    # Create an empty set
    unique_labels_len = set()
    
    # Iterate over all mask dataset
    for mask in masks:
        
        # Read mask
        test_mask = io.imread(mask)
        
        # Find unique labels in the mask
        unique_labels = np.unique(test_mask)
        
        # Find the total number of unique labels
        len_unique_labels = len(unique_labels)
        
        # Add to the set
        unique_labels_len.add(len_unique_labels)

    # Find the maximum label length
    max_label_len = max(unique_labels_len)
    
    # Convert to list and sort
    unique_labels_len = list(unique_labels_len)
    unique_labels_len.sort()
    
    # Print results
    print(f" Number of labels across all masks: {unique_labels_len} \n Maximum number of masks: {max_label_len}")

    return max_label_len

NUM_CLASSES = check_mask_labels(masks)
```

Output:

Number of labels across all masks: [1, 30, 34, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64]

Maximum number of masks: 64

Masks have a different number of labels as expected. The above code will give you the number of classes you need to put in the model.